# Is it safe to pass local variables as method parameters inside of a block?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, local-variables, retain-cycle

I know blocks in Obj-C allow you to reference local variables, which is nice. But can we safely pass local variables to another method from inside of a block?

I know referencing self can be dangerous from inside blocks, but does this extend to any other variables.

Example:

```
-(void)methodTakesObject(ObjectA *)object {

    ObjectB *b = object.b;
    __weak MyObject *weakSelf = self;

    [b doInBackground:^(NSArray *results) {
         [weakSelf doSomethingElseWith:results andWith:object andEvenWith:b];
    }
}
```

There are three "types" of local variables here. the `results` from the block, the `ObjectB` created inside the method, and an `ObjectA` which was passed to the method to start.

Should I be concerned about using any of these variables, and indeed is there any difference/concerns between how these variables are treated from within the block

Comment: The block will keep a strong reference to all of the variables. Hence, you should have no concerns about using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it makes no difference no matter what variables are involved.

The concern with a retain cycle is if an object holds a strong reference to a block *that it isn't expected to release until it is deallocated* while the block holds a strong reference to that same object. That's not happening here.

A method called `-doInBackground:` seems like it will run the block (starting immediately-ish) and then release the block when it finishes. So, there's no prospect of the block being kept around as long as some other object exists, thus there's no prospect of it keeping that other object around forever.

You don't even need to use the weak-self convention to avoid a retain cycle here. You would only use it in the unlikely case that you really want to allow `self` to sometimes be deallocated before the block calls its method. More likely, you should just use a normal, strong reference to `self` because it's normal and/or desirable for `self` to live long enough for the block to execute.

Comment: "and then release the block when it finishes. So, there's no prospect of the block being kept around as long as some other object exists, thus there's no prospect of it keeping that other object around forever." That's all a guess based on the name. I wouldn't rely on that.

Comment: @newacct: All of the names in the example were clearly changed to be generic. If the generic name chosen for that method did not indicate how it behaves, then it was chosen badly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about retain cycle, **@ken** gave you the perfect answer. As for the concerns about variables:

1. `object` is retained from the method that called
   `methodTakesObject:` so you don't have to worry about it. (if it isn't *nil*, tho).
2. `b` is also retained by you, the reference count is likely 2 or
   more, so you also don't have to worry about it.

In other words, you are safe.